how to run fastapi with a specific python interpreter on linux
I'm (trying to) run FastAPI on a linux container that has multiple versions of python.  When I do fastapi run, I want fastapi to run using a particular python interpreter. (e.g. I want it to use the python at /usr/bin/python3.12 instead of at /usr/bin/python3.9.
How do I do that?

The fastapi 'binary' is only present in the python environment in which it is installed. You decide which python you are using by determining which fastapi 'binary' you are calling. You should be able to determine the one you are actually using with which fastapi in most cases. If you want to know where the fastapi of your preferred environment is, one way to do it is to run that particular python, and check sys.path(). That should tell you where your site packages folder is, and you can look there for the fastapi executable. While I haven't checked, it'll probably be in the bin directory close to the site packages folder, probably one or two levels up.
If you have fastapi in multiple environments, you can call fastapi with the full path to the fastapi binary of the particular environment you want to use, or adjust your $PATH of that terminal to ensure the correct one is selected.
If you're planning on maintaining multiple python versions and environments, though, I strongly suggest you look into using pyenv + virtualenv, which will help manage these things for you.
When you're operating in a container, however, there is something to be said about NOT having multiple python versions living side by side, so consider if you really need those. The whole point is to have a well specified environment with exactly the things you need at exactly the right versions and not much more.

Thanks Chintalagiri.  I agree that a container with multiple version of Python is bonkers.  But for various reasons, I need run a container based on the Amazon Linux 2023 image.  That image uses Python 3.9 for a bunch of stuff, so you have to keep it.  But I want to use Python 3.12 for features in the app I'm running with FastAPI.  Hence 2 Pythons in my container!

In Python, you should use "virtualenvs"  (sometimes called "venv"s) to separate your projects: each project should have its own venv - there are a couple tools to create these, including the venv module that comes along with Python itself.
This alone allows one to control which libraries, and library versions are configured for each project, isolated from the system Python.
All you need to do to use a specific Python version for a project is to create the virtualenv using your wanted Python version, and then activate it to install all of your projects requirement (including FastAPI).
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
Also, to manage several Python versions on the same machine, and being able to create virtualenvs with each of them, use the "pyenv" project. (not needed if you already got your wanted Python vesions installed and working): https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

To run FastAPI using a specific Python interpreter when you have multiple versions of Python installed, you can follow these steps:
Option 1: Use the Full Path to Python
Install FastAPI and Uvicorn:
Ensure that you have FastAPI and Uvicorn installed for the specific Python interpreter. You can do this by specifying the full path to the Python interpreter when installing packages.
/usr/bin/python3.12 -m pip install fastapi uvicorn

Run FastAPI with the Specific Python Interpreter:
Use the specific Python interpreter to run the Uvicorn server. This way, FastAPI will be run using the Python version you specified.
/usr/bin/python3.12 -m uvicorn your_app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

Here, replace your_app:app with the appropriate import path for your FastAPI application.
Option 2: Use a Virtual Environment
Create a Virtual Environment with the Desired Python Version:
You can create a virtual environment that uses the specific Python interpreter.
/usr/bin/python3.12 -m venv myenv

Activate the Virtual Environment:
Activate the virtual environment. This will ensure that any Python commands (including installing packages) use the Python version of the virtual environment.
source myenv/bin/activate

Install FastAPI and Uvicorn in the Virtual Environment:
With the virtual environment activated, install FastAPI and Uvicorn.
pip install fastapi uvicorn

Run FastAPI Using the Virtual Environment:
Now, you can run FastAPI using the uvicorn command from within the virtual environment.
uvicorn your_app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

Option 3: Use a Shebang Line (for Scripts)
If you’re running a script to start FastAPI, you can specify the Python interpreter at the top of your script using a shebang line.
Create a Python Script (e.g., start_server.py):
#!/usr/bin/python3.12
import uvicorn
from your_app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

Make the Script Executable:
chmod +x start_server.py

Run the Script:
./start_server.py

By following any of these approaches, you can ensure that FastAPI runs using the desired Python interpreter.
